# Json formatter for traits in Play 2.4

Tags: json, playframework, traits

Am having a trait

```
  trait Role[A, B] {
    val _id: Option[A] = None
    val value: Option[List[B]] = None
    val id: Option[String] = None
  }
```

And the case class extending the trait

```
case class User (value1: Option[Role] = None, value2: Option[String] = None) extends Role

object User { 
implicit val jsonFormatter: Format[User] = Json.format[User]
}
```

And it is not compiling because of the error, "No Json formattor for Role".

I tried several examples available in stackoverflow, on json formatter for traits Nothing gets worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, since when **Play** try to do a formatting for User, it doesn't know how to format `Role` to json.

You could do that, by first adding something like:

```
implicit val roleFormat = Json.format[Role]
```

to the `object User`

Requirements from the Play documentation:

> These macros rely on a few assumptions about the type they’re working
> with :
>
> - It must have a companion object having apply and unapply methods
> - The return types of the unapply must match the argument types of the apply method.
> - The parameter names of the apply method must be the same as the property names desired in the JSON.
>
> Case classes natively meet these requirements. For more custom classes
> or traits, you might have to implement them.